# No module at PythonShell (Deployed Google Firebase node.js function running a python script, ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, shell, google-cloud-platform

I have a Firebase functions project. This is my project setup:

[image: Folder structure in VSCode]

The index.js script executes app.py through a PythonShell.

When running locally, the executed python script works just fine (Probably because all dependencies are installed and found on my computer).

However when I deploy it to Firebase and the python script gets executed I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

This is the log in my google console:

```
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rembg' at PythonShell.parseError (/workspace/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:303:21) at terminateIfNeeded (/workspace/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:193:32) at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:185:13) at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28) at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:552:15) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12) at Process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

I am sure it is because the python script can't find the modules that I try to import in app.py

According to the Google Docs [Specifying dependencies in Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python?hl=de#python38)
I added the requirements.txt file just next to my python script as you can see in the picture above. But this doesn't help although I thought as it get's deployed the dependencies in the requirements.txt get installed automatically.

So I opened my GCP Shell and tried to install the dependencies with pip.
That worked, but then there also is a warning it's not on the PATH.

Which python returns:

> /usr/bin/python

and which python3 returns

> /usr/bin/python3

As I am very new to this I am not quite sure how to set the path or somehow make the python dependencies visible for my python script that runs on the Google Cloud.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just figured out this is not possible. It does not work because the Python Shell runs inside a node js environment. And thus it's not working

Comment: You can file in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/) for feature requests, So the Product team will check on it. However, there is no ETA for it.